# Why the dataGridView1 when adding columns to it it's adding one more empty column at the bottom?

Tags: c#, winforms

there are 200 links in the List  links.

```
private void PopulateGridWithNewData(List<string> links)
{
    foreach (var link in links)
    {
        columnsCounter++;

        UpdateUI(() =>
        {
            downloadList.Add(new DataGrid()
            {
                ColumnsCounter = columnsCounter,
                FileName = radar.linksandfilesnames[link] + ".png",
                Status = "Pending",
                Link = link
            });
        });
    }

    // Refresh the DataGridView to show the new list.
    dataGridView1.DataSource = downloadList;
    dataGridView1.Refresh();
}
```

it is adding 200 links but at the bottom it's adding one emptier column.

in the image screenshot on the left side is the top of the columns starting by 1 and on the right it's the bottom ending by 200 but in the end after the number 200 there is empty line.

i put a breakpoint on the line

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = downloadList;
```

and downloadList contain 200 items links.

[image: dataGridView1 columns count 200 and one empty in the bottom in the end.]